# Error building Docker image with bootJar task

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker, gradle, dockerfile

I am trying to build a Docker image for my Java Spring Boot application. So I created a Docker file like this:

```
FROM openjdk:17-jdk-alpine
VOLUME /tmp
ARG JAR_FILE
COPY ${JAR_FILE} media-service.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "/media-service.jar"]
FROM openjdk:17-jdk-alpine
VOLUME /tmp
WORKDIR /media-service
COPY build/libs/media-service-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar media-service.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "media-service.jar"]
# Run bootJar task to generate executable jar file
RUN ./gradlew bootJar
# Copy the generated jar file into the container
COPY build/libs/media-service-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar media-service.jar
```

Then I realized when trying to run the image that I have to add the main classpath, so I added this in my build.gradle file:

```
bootJar {
    mainClass = 'com.emanuel.mediaservice.MediaServiceApplication'
}
```

Tested the generated jar file with the command `java -jar myJar.jar` and it works fine.
After adding the main classpath, I changed the docker file to run the bootJar task so I can have a functional jar.

Here is the updated Dockerfile:

```
FROM openjdk:17-jdk-alpine

# Set working directory to /media-service
WORKDIR /media-service

# Copy Gradle files
COPY build.gradle .
COPY gradlew .
COPY gradle gradle

# Download dependencies
RUN ./gradlew dependencies

# Copy source code
COPY src/main src/main
COPY src/test src/test

# Build executable jar file
RUN ./gradlew bootJar

# Copy executable jar file into container
COPY build/libs/media-service-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar media-service.jar

# Set command to run when the container starts
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "media-service.jar"]
```

But now unfortunatley **I get this errors**: https://pastebin.com/WJuBiVhD

I will also like to mention that I use this plugin https://github.com/palantir/gradle-docker
and I will also like to share how I use it in my build.gradle:

```
plugins {
//...
    id 'com.palantir.docker' version '0.35.0'
}

docker {
    name "media-service"
    dockerfile file('src/main/docker/Dockerfile')
    copySpec.from(jar).rename(".*", "media-service.jar")
    buildArgs(['JAR_FILE': "media-service.jar"])
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two errors.

1. `/gradlew` was not found.
2. The JAR file in `/build` was not found; probably because the Gradle command could not be executed.

Rather than write your own Dockerfile and fiddle with running Gradle within it, I would highly recommend you use [jib-gradle-plugin](https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/jib/tree/master/jib-gradle-plugin)

Otherwise, Spring Boot already has a gradle action for building a container using BuildPacks, and you don't need other plugins.

```
./gradlew bootBuildImage --imageName=media-service
```

Comment: This was my first attempt, then I tried it with the jib plugin: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76117853/docker-image-cant-connect-to-localhost-ports