# Docker image can't connect to localhost ports

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, docker

I created a Docker image for my SpringBoot application with the Jib plugin and for some reason, I get errors because my container can't connect to my local Postgres database and my local Zipkin server.

I tried to run the app like this:

```
docker run --network host -p 8080:8080 media-service
docker run --network=host media-service
docker run --network=host --add-host host.docker.internal:host-gateway media-service
docker run --network host --add-host host.docker.internal:host-gateway media-service
docker run --add-host host.docker.internal:host-gateway media-service
```

And I also added this in my "pg_hba.conf" to allow docker connections:

```
# all connections from the Docker network subnet
host    all        all      172.16.0.0/12   trust
```

Here is a snippet of my log:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name
'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource
[org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build 
Hibernate SessionFactory
...
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: 
Unable to open JDBC Connection for DDL execution
...
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Connection to localhost:5432 refused. Check
that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP
connections.
...
Exception in thread "Thread-3" zipkin2.reporter.ClosedSenderException
```

Here is the full log: https://pastebin.com/pMjcvyms

Comment: I think you need to connect through IP (127.0.0.1) instead of localhost or `host.docker.internal`

Comment: Do you mean the command ```docker run ..``` is wrong or that I should modify my spring boot config to accept 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost?

Comment: I mean the connection string for your DB in spring config

Comment: Are you using Docker Desktop (on any platform) or some other VM-based Docker implementation?  `--network=host` doesn't work unless you're using Docker Engine directly on a native-Linux system.

Comment: I have Docker Desktop, I am using Windows.

Comment: @grekier I tried to replace localhost with 127.0.0.1 in applcation.properties, but unfortunately, it did not work. I get the same behavior.

Comment: `127.0.0.1` and `localhost` are almost always the same thing. Neither are correct here

Answer (score 1):

> my container can't connect to my local Postgres database

Your container isn't running Postgres, and `--network=host` doesn't work in Windows for accessing services running directly in Windows.

Best option would be to run Postgres as its own container, then connect the two, such as using Docker Compose.

Otherwise, without seeing your Spring Config, you should reference [Boot Configuration](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/data.html#data.sql.r2dbc) and use the address **other than** localhost, such as `postgresql://docker.host.internal`

You shouldn't need extra `--add-host` flags.

Comment: So there is no way of connecting the spring-boot container to my local Postgres database?

Comment: That's not what I said. As answered, you need to remove `--host` flags and connect to `host.docker.internal` rather than `localhost` since that's referencing the container itself. **Or** run Postgres in a second container